# Compute the limit of the sequence $x_n=(2-\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt[3]{2})...(2-\sqrt[n]{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

At the end of the book where I got the problem it says that the limit is $0$; therefore, I have tried to majorize with a sequence having also limit $0$. Then I have looked at the series obtained by taking $\log(x_n)$ and trying to prove that it goes to $-\infty$.

Comment: you can bound the sequence and apply squeeze theorem

Comment: Rewrite $2^{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp(\frac{1}{n}\ln(2))\rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking logs, any term of $$\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \log \left(2-2^{1/k}\right)$$ is negative and decreasing.

In other words, as
$$\log (2-2^x)=-x \log (2)+O\left(x^2\right);\;\text{ as } x\to 0$$
we have
$$\log \left(2-2^{1/k}\right)\sim -\frac{\log (2)}{k};\;\text{ as }k\to\infty$$
The sum is equivalent to $$(-\log 2)\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac1k$$
diverges to $-\infty$ thus the product converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\ln(x_n) &=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}) \\
\iff\frac{1}{n}\ln(x_n) &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(2-2^{\frac{1}{n}})  \tag{1}\\
\end{align}
And we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(2-2^{\frac{1}{n}}) \longrightarrow \int_0^1\ln(2-2^x)dx \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
Using Mathematica, I found that
$$\int_0^1\ln(2-2^x)dx=\frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{\ln(4096)} \approx -0.839996 \tag{3}$$
From (1), (2) and (3), we have
$$\ln(x_n) = n \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{\ln(4096)} \right) \longrightarrow -\infty $$
or
$$x_n \longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: No need to calculate integral, just note that $\ln(2-2^x)$ is decreasing and less than zero for $x\in(0,1)$.